# how to display detailed information after clicking a gridview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Sorry bad english.. 
I want to navigate from one screen to another base on id from gridview items.
when one of the listview item11 is clicked it will be directed to the detail page item11..
So, how do create a detailed page design when one of the ListView's clicks is different.

full my code:

```
class CategoryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SafeArea(
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new BankAndaAppBar(),

        body: new Container(

          color: Colors.grey[100],
          child: new ListView(
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, right: 12.0, top: 12.0),
                  color: Colors.grey[100],
                  child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _bodyGridView(),
                    ],
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _bodyGridView() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            children: CATEGORIES_DUMMY_DATA
                .map((cat) => ListCategory(cat.id, cat.title, cat.titleDetail, cat.description, cat.image))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }    
}
```

I want display detailed information after clicking a gridview item. 
example : every clicking a item 1 show detail view item=1.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTM20.jpg)
Thanks.

Comment: Please add some of your code , what you have done.

Comment: already added the code sir..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to display detailed information after clicking a grid item.

If so, there are many ways to do it.

1. Pass the data within pages : [follow](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)
2. Create a model class, store the data in memory and display it. [follow](https://medium.com/flutter-community/fetching-data-in-flutter-and-displaying-in-listview-ec1bb72af22c)

If you want to navigate from one screen to another [follow](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

Comment: ya I want navigate from one screen to another but different content data. Thanks sir.